# Cannot invoke service on live url

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I created a wcf service which is attached to eveleep sql database which returns the a everleap.com database. I debuged my code locally to esnure that I can retreieve the test data and i did but when tried to work on it live url of

> http://1937-6187.el-alt.com/curoService.svc

It gives me the following error

> ![Blockquote] 
>   [image]

Is their some things I need to change in webconfig to allow it to work with a remote url its does indead retreieve the methods and use can test it yourselfs but it doesnt return the json just

I have encluded my web config in case their is anything else i need to set in it I have hidde my passwords for obvious reasons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="Curo.curoService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4568/                           Design_Time_Addresses/Curo/curoService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Curo.IcuroService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
 <add name="curoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CuroDB.csdl|res://*/CuroDB.ssdl|res://*/CuroDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=s03.everleap.com;initial catalog=DB_1937_curo;persist security info=True;user id=********_user;password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Edit1**
When I change the locahost values to the following web.config i get the following error.

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://1937-6187.el-alt.com/curoService.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://1937-6187.el-alt.com/curoService.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://1937-6187.el-alt.com/curoService.svc'.    The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '   IIS 8.5 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error  http://1937-6187.el-alt.com/curoService.svc    There was an error downloading 'http://1937-6187.el-alt.com/curoService.svc'.    The request failed with the error message:--   IIS 8.5 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> #### HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.     Detailed Error Information:            ModuleÿÿÿIIS Web Core     NotificationÿÿÿUnknown     HandlerÿÿÿNot yet determined     Error Codeÿÿÿ0x8007000d     Config ErrorÿÿÿConfiguration file is not well-formed XML Config Fileÿÿÿ\?\C:\inetpub\temp\DWASFiles\Sites\1937-6187\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\web.config                   Requested URLÿÿÿhttp://1937-6187.el-alt.com:80/curoService.svc     Physical Pathÿÿÿ     Logon MethodÿÿÿNot yet determined     Logon UserÿÿÿNot yet determined                                Config Source:
>
> ```
>     1: ?        2:
> ```
>
> More Information:   This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.
>
> [View more information ¯](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=500,19,0x8007000d,9600)
>
> --.

Adjusted web config which creates above error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="Curo.curoService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://1937-6187.el-alt.com/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Curo.IcuroService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="http://1937-6187.el-alt.com/" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="curoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CuroDB.csdl|res://*/CuroDB.ssdl|res://*/CuroDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=s03.everleap.com;initial catalog=DB_1937_curo;persist security info=True;user id=DB_1937_curo_user;password=Lisa2015d;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

The strange thing is it returns the methods fine but when i click invoke it returns the second error whe i change from local host to live host.

Full stack trace suggests some kind of authentication error but thats not case username and password is correct in web.config

> The caller was not authenticated by the service.

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenProvider.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IcuroService.GetPersonById(Int32 PersonId)
   at IcuroServiceClient.GetPersonById(Int32 PersonId)

Inner Exception:
The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
```

Comment: Did you try using the DNS address in the service endpoint vs `localhost`?  Also, please post the complete exception and stack trace - screen shots cut off important information and not everyone ca see them.

Comment: @Tim yes please see edit sorry for not incuding that

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who suffers from the same problem I simply changed this line

> endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding"
>   contract="Curo.IcuroService"

To work with basicHttpsBinding i dont noof the security implications of this is this advised if hooking form a phone app